# ui5 project uploaded on the server not working (working in Eclipse)

Tags: sapui5

I have a small ui5 project in Eclipse and it is working on my local machine. But when I submit the project on our SAP Server as a BSP Application it is not working.  All I see is a blue empty web page.

On the console, there is an error: Controller xxx.xxx couldn't be instantiated.

What could be the problem is? Do you people see that something like that before?

Denizhan

Comment: Wrong path in manifest or Component? can you show your faulty controller and the whole error?

Comment: Is it able to find but not load the controller? The error should tell you if it can't find the file. If it can find it but not load it, try commenting out any code in the onInit or onAfterRendering methods -- errors in these methods can prevent the controller from loading. once we narrow it down we can help find a solution

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the controller name and the controller file name to be **exactly** the same?

Windows is case insensitive, so it might work locally. But it will fail when deployed to a Unix system.

Comment: I checked that but it is not about it. So I decided to build new project in Eclipse and not changed it structure and it is worked.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved by a new project. Did not change eclipse structure (controller code structure I mean) and it worked on the server.